# Can't grant privileges to users on Azure MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, azure, mysql-error-1044

yesterday I deployed a MySQL database image from the Azure marketplace. It is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/overview/) issued by Microsoft. I can connect with the user I specified in the Azure portal and was able to create an additional user for testing purposes and grant it all privileges on two different databases. However, if try to do the same today I get the infamous `Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'`. I have read that some MySQL versions on Azure do not support user privilege handling, but I was already able to do it with this image version. I even verified that the created user had access to the specified databases and inserting/selecting data from it was also working. I have tried setting up a fresh database with a new testuser to no avail, as i received the same error. This is basically what I did:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pw';
GRANT INSERT  ON db.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pw';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After the user was created I also checked with `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'%'` for the given permissions and they were there. The admin user specified in the Azure portal also has grant_priv privileges. Can someone please help me to understand why all of a sudden it is not possible for me to grant even simple privileges to newly created users? It should be possible as [this Blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/06/26/grant-super-privilege-on-azure-database-for-mysql/) from an Microsoft employee suggests. Clearly I am missing something as such a basic feature should be included.